# CasperJS script not calling a function only when executed from a shell script which itself is executed from Java

Tags: java, bash, shell, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a script written in Casper.js. I am using a Java Process to execute a shell script which executes the Casper script.

Almost all of the Casper script runs when I execute it this way (confirmed by console logs and `this.echo()` commands) except for one function, and I don't know why. Here's a snippet:

```
this.then(function() {
            this.click('input[type="type"]');
            this.then(function() {
                this.page.uploadFile('input[type="type"]', 'picture.jpg');
                this.then(function() {
                    this.wait(1000);
                    this.then(function() {
                        var test = this.evaluate(function() {
                            return document.getElementById('elementid').value;
                        });
                        this.echo(test);
                        return test;
                    });
```

The function in question that is not being called is the callback function for assigning a value to the variable `test`.

It works perfectly when I execute the shell script on my computer. This only fails when it is called from my Java program.

Any insight on the matter would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You say that it "fails", but what does it mean? Do you see an error? Is the output blank? Does it simply skip and not print this line, but still prints later lines?

Comment: I should have been more specific, my bad. There is no error. It seems as though it skips that function entirely, since my console.log debugging statements don't print at all if I add them in. So ```this.echo(test)``` outputs nothing at all.

Comment: Does it print something (even if it is a blank line) when you comment the code inside `evaluate`? If so, then I suggest that you check whether `document.getElementById('elementid')` is not null.

Comment: It doesn't print anything at all, not even a blank line. I know that ```document.getElementById('elementId')``` is not null because it works as expected when executed in a "normal" context (i.e. go to Terminal, and type: ./mybashscript.sh).

I did change Eclipse's environment to include my PATH variable so that it can have access to the ```casperjs``` command and phantomjs.

Comment: You have to debug a little more. a) change `this.wait(1000)` to `this.waitForSelector('#elementid')` b) add a `this.echo("starting test")` before the `evaluate` call. What do you see?